# The number of $3×3$ matrices $A$ whose entries are either $0$ or $1$ and for which the following system has exactly two distinct solutions.

Tags: matrices, determinant

The number of $3×3$ matrices $A$ whose entries are either $0$ or $1$ and for which the system has exactly two distinct solutions.

$$A\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$adj(A)=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11}&C_{21}&C_{31}\\
C_{12}&C_{22}&C_{32}\\
C_{13}&C_{23}&C_{33}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$adj(A)(A)\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=adj(A)\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
|A|&0&0\\
0&|A|&0\\
0&0&|A|
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=adj(A)\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Case $1$: $y=x$ and $z\ne x$ and $|A|\ne0$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
|A|&0&0\\
0&|A|&0\\
0&0&|A|
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11}&C_{21}&C_{31}\\
C_{12}&C_{22}&C_{32}\\
C_{13}&C_{23}&C_{33}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
|A|&0&0\\
0&|A|&0\\
0&0&|A|
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
C_{11}\\
C_{12}\\
C_{13}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
|A|&0&0\\
0&|A|&0\\
0&0&|A|
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
x\\
z
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
A_{22}A_{33}-A_{23}A_{32}\\
A_{23}A_{31}-A_{21}A_{33}\\
A_{21}A_{32}-A_{22}A_{31}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$A_{22}A_{33}-A_{23}A_{32}=A_{23}A_{31}-A_{21}A_{33}\tag{1}$$
$$A_{21}A_{32}-A_{22}A_{31}\ne A_{22}A_{33}-A_{23}A_{32}\tag{2}$$

Let's see equation $1$
$$A_{21}A_{33}+A_{22}A_{33}-(A_{23}A_{32}+A_{23}A_{31})=0$$

Let's say $A_{21}A_{33}=1$, then we have 
$$1+A_{22}-A_{23}A_{32}-A_{23}A_{31}=0$$

Let's say $A_{23}=0$, then we have $1+A_{22}=0$, now this is not possible so $A_{23}=1$

$$1+A_{22}-A_{32}-A_{31}=0$$

If $A_{22}=1$, then both $A_{32}$ and $A_{31}$ has to be one

If $A_{22}=0$, then exactly one of $A_{32}$ and $A_{31}$ has to be one

So there are three possible structures for $A_{21}A_{33}=1$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
?&?&?\\
1&1&1\\
1&1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
?&?&?\\
1&0&1\\
1&0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
?&?&?\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

But only third structure is valid as first two don't satisfy equation $2$

We also have to ensure that determinant is non-zero, so 
$$|A|=A_{11}(0-1)-A_{12}(1-0)+A_{13}(1-0)$$
$$|A|=-A_{11}-A_{12}+A_{13}$$

Now here $|A|=0$ only when all $A_{11},A_{12},A_{13}$ are zero or $A_{11}=1,A_{13}=1,A_{12}=0$ or $A_{12}=1,A_{13}=1,A_{11}=0$. So total no of possible matrices are $5$

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1\\
1&0&1\\
0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Now there can be too many cases because only for $x=y,x\ne z,|A|\ne 0,A_{21}A_{33}=1$ we got $5$ possible matrices. It is getting difficult to calculate in this way.

Any other way which we can think of?

Comment: no, they can be anything

Comment: but I have got the five solutions, can you take a look at them

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  So are $x$, $y$, and $z$ fixed values?

Comment: these are the variables, they are not fixed

Comment: see I have put the question as it is from the source

Comment: How do you get exactly two solutions? Surely you always get either 0, 1 or infinitely many?